# I am not able to get the value form JSP page to Controller Class on Submit

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, liferay-6

This code is wriiten in Liferay 6.1 platform.

Description: I have one drop down menu by name "Store Name". I will select any one of the value from drop down and pass that value to javascript function "getStoreDetails" onchange. The sent value from this function will be checked in the javascript array "lNames", If value is present in this array then index will be obtained and using index we obtain value from "fNames" array and add to span class "FirstName". I am able to do this and code is working fine.

Problem:I am not able to get FirstName value from jsp file to Controller Class of submitIssue method.

This is my Controller class

```
public class IssueController{

public String handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request));

User user = PortalUtil.getUser(httpRequest);

model.addAttribute("my_user", user);

/*Some code goes here to set user attributes like department and organization using model object */

return "issue";    /*This is my jsp file mentioned below*/

}

@ActionMapping
public void submitIssue(@ModelAttribute IssueForm submitIssueForm, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortalException, SystemException, IOException, PortletException {

       String First_Name=request.getParameter("FirstName");
       System.out.println("First Name while submitting is :\t"+First_Name);

       /* here i am not able to obtain value of First_Name */
   }

}
```

The below code is my issue.jsp file

```
   <div class="large-4 medium-8 small-12 columns">
                Store Name <select
                    class="no-highlight" id="StoreName_dropdown"
                    name="storeName"
                    onchange="getStoreDetails(this.value);"

                    <%

                    String stores[] = new String[] {"1021","1022","1023","1024","1025","1026","1027","1028","1029","1030"};

                    for(int i=0;i<stores.length;i++){%>

                    <option value="<%=stores[i]%>"><%=stores[i]%></option>

                    <%}%>

                </select>
  </div>
  <%
     String fNames[] = new String[] {"John1021","wilson1022","test1023","test1024","test1025","test1026","test1027","test1028","test1029","test1030"};
        StringBuffer bufferfNames = new StringBuffer();
        bufferfNames.append("[");
        for(int i=0; i<fNames.length; i++){

            bufferfNames.append("\"").append(fNames[i]).append("\"");
                if(i+1 < fNames.length){
                    bufferfNames.append(",");
                }
        }
        bufferfNames.append("]");
        String First_Name=bufferfNames.toString();

        String lNames[] = new String[] {"1021","1022","1023","1024","1025","1026","1027","1028","1029","1030"}; 

        StringBuffer bufferlNames = new StringBuffer();
        bufferlNames.append("[");
        for(int i=0; i<lNames.length; i++){

            bufferlNames.append("\"").append(lNames[i]).append("\"");
                if(i+1 < lNames.length){
                    bufferlNames.append(",");
                }
        }
        bufferlNames.append("]");
        String Last_Name=bufferlNames.toString();
  %>
  <div class="row ">
            <div class="large-3 medium-4 columns">
                <span class="firstName">First Name : &nbsp;&nbsp; <span
                    class="hide-for-medium-up"><b>"dynamically name added"</b></span></span>
                <div class="hide-for-small" id="FirstName" >
                    <b>"dynamically name added"</b>
                </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row ">
        <div class="large-2 medium-3 columns">
                <button class="submitIssue submit_button"
                    id="submitIssue" tabIndex=9>
                    Submit
                </button>
        </div>
</div>

 <script>
 function getStoreDetails(store) {

    var fNames=<%=First_Name%>;
    var lNames=<%=Last_Name%>;
    var index;

    index=lNames.indexOf(store);

    if (index > -1) {
        document.getElementById("FirstName").innerHTML = fNames[index];  
    }
   else{
       alert("Store is not present in lNames !!");
   }
 }
 </script>
```

My javascript program in separate file submitIssue.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       $('button.submitIssue').click(function(){
       $('#submitIssueForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Can anyone suggest me to get this value. Please comment in case if you have not understood my problem statement. thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot find where you have put the firstname as a request parameter neither the submit code (or button)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see "FirstName" printed in your jsp? If yes, you need to pass this value in input tag, so that you can expect this value to come in your controller. Hope this helps!!

Comment: First Name Value will be changed each time I change option in drop down menu. so when I try to print it , it will print "null"

Comment: use toString method on your javascript variables. For ex - lNames.toString().indexOf(store.toString)

Comment: Yes I am able to see the value in my JSP.. If I do as you said it will be string formed from array lNames which is having multiple names. like String lNames[]={"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"........"NameN"};   I will display  only one name in JSP using "index", so whatever it prints I have to read it to Controller class.